# In Unity, when are dependencies determined through reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection, dependency-injection, dependencies, unity-container

Aside from registered dependencies, are dependencies that are determined through reflection, such as injected dependencies, done in regards to the lifetime of the dependency or during the lifetime of the DI Container?

Edit: DI Container in mind is Unity.

Edit: Elaboration: I am curious how many times the reflection process occurs, and also wanted clarity regarding weather or not the stage in the Unity build that uses reflection will find constructors and properties.  The fourth stage in the Unity build, according to the MSDN ( [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.objectbuilder.unitybuildstage%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) ), is "Precreation" being the "Fourth stage. Reflection over constructors, properties, etc. is performed here." How many times is this stage run? Once during the construction of the container, or every time constructor and property dependencies need to be resolved? Which part of the Register Resolve Release pattern does this occur in?

Comment: Each DI container works in a different way. Do you have a particular one in mind?

Comment: Yes, the DI Container that I have been working with is Unity. I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what is being asked here. Can you elaborate? Perhaps include your reason for asking?

Comment: @MarkSeemann - I edited with elaboration, I hope that clarifies the question.

Comment: I'm wondering *why* you want to know this?

Comment: I like being aware of what is going on behind the scenes, and also I am trying to make sure I understand what Unity is doing so I can properly use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity uses a build pipeline called `StrategyChain` to create objects. This pipeline is run every time you resolve an object from the container.

Each step in that pipeline is implemented as a strategy. These strategies lookup values called `BuilderPolicies`. These policies encapsulate information a strategy has accumulated (like using reflection to determine which constructor to use, which properties to inject etc.). The first time you run the pipeline for a specific type the strategies put policies into a store called `PolicyList`. The next time the pipeline is asked to build that type those values will be reused so the effort involved should only cost you once.

---

**UPDATE**

I guess you mean ASP.NET? Actually there are two `PolicyLists`. One which only lives for one cycle through the `StrategyChain` (transient) and one which is coupled to the lifetime of the container. It lives as long as your instance of the `UnityContainer` is not disposed or garbage collected. One thing that might be interesting to you: You can't serialize your container. Thus you can't tell an application running on a web farm to store it in a cache and share it between servers.

Comment: What is the lifetime of the PolicyList? In the scenario of .net, is it per session?

Comment: Thank you for the update, I appreciate it. Assume that every resolved object is immediately released (let the time it takes to be used approach 0 ms). Resolving and releasing an object 100 times would then only use reflection to determine the pipeline once (as long as the container is not garbage collected)?

Comment: @TravisJ If your objects are registered with a transient/per resolve lifetime they would be resolved, used and then garbage collected like any other CLR object. If they are registered with a singleton lifetime that single instance would be reused and thus not collected. After the first resolve there should be no need for the container to use reflection again.